# How can I get certain text from a website with Python?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am using a python script to get a certain text from a website (http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/). For example trying this search: http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/links?site=www.google.com

I would like to get "Page Authority" and "Root Domains" and filter them out.I am using lxml.

I am using this code:

```
response = br.open( 'http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/links?site=' + blog)
tree = html.fromstring(response.read())
authority = int (tree.xpath('//span[@class="metrics-authority"]/text()')[1].strip())
if authority>1:
    print blog
    print 'This blog is ready to be registered'
    print authority
    f.write(blog +' '+ str(authority) +'\n')
```

Here I am filtering for a PA greater than 1 and I would like also to filter for Linking Root Domains greater than 5. How can I do that?

Comment: `x/text()` is almost always a bad idea in XPath: prefer `string(x)`.

Comment: Isn't the "root domains" information in the fourth div.has-tooltip?

Comment: @larsmans Thanks for that info. I am really newbie into python and I didn't know that.
So could you give me an example on how this will be implemented?
I guess it is something like this:
`authority = tree.xpath('string(class="metrics-authority")')[1].strip()`

Comment: @Fury for example if you search for [http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/links?site=www.google.com] I like to scrape the 680k number out of there. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all 2 spans with `metrics-authority` class, first one is a `Domain Authority`, second one is a `Page Authority`. Additionally, you can get `Root Domains` from the `div` with `id="metrics-page-link-metrics"`:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import html

tree = html.parse(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/links?site=www.google.com'))

spans = tree.xpath('//span[@class="metrics-authority"]')
data = [item.text.strip() for item in spans]
print "Domain Authority: {0}, Page Authority: {1}".format(*data)

div = tree.xpath('//div[@id="metrics-page-link-metrics"]//div[@class="has-tooltip"]')[1]
print "Root Domains: {0}".format(div.text.strip())
```

prints:

```
Domain Authority: 100, Page Authority: 97 
Root Domains: 680
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the code but what I really need is Root Domains instead of Domain Authority in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the info @alecxe it is really useful, but I have updated my code. Just now I would like to have PA and Root Domains in 2 variables but first filter them. I will need PA>1 and Root Domains>5. I don't need DA metric.

Comment: @alexgarciab this is a game changer. Make a separate question about the problem instead of updating the existing. Thanks.

Comment: I guess it is not a good idea to publish duplicate content over here @alecxe - I just want to know how to extract these values and store them in variables.